# Can I use Papermill and Scrapbook with AWS EMR Notebooks?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, papermill

I have several notebooks which are ran by a "driver" notebook using papermill. These notebooks use the scrapbook library to communicate information to the driver. The driver then passes this information as parameters to other notebooks. I want to use EMR Notebooks to optimize the execution efficiency of this "notebook pipeline". Does AWS EMR Notebooks support scrapbook and papermill or will I need to refactor my notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, nope. You can't do that directly.
What you can do though (what we are doing) is as follows :

1. Create a python environment on your EMR masternode using the `hadoop` user
2. Install [sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic) in your environment and configure all kernels as described in the README.md file for sparkmagic
3. Copy your notebook to master node/use it directly from s3 location
4. Install papermill and run with papermill :

   papermill s3://path/to/notebook/input.ipynb s3://path/to/notebook/output.ipynb -p param=1